# DataReader is not getting values

Tags: c#

```
DateTime dtExpiry = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

CommonFunctionDAL objCommDAL = new CommonFunctionDAL();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_LoginCheck", sqlconnection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@UserName", emailid);
SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@Password", password);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

SqlParameter sEMPID = cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Int, 5);
sEMPID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

sqlconnection.Open();

SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (rd.HasRows) 
{
    rd.Read();

    HttpCookie AppCookies = new HttpCookie("AppCookies");
    AppCookies["EMPID"] = rd["EMPID"].ToString();
    AppCookies["AEMPID"] = rd["AEMPID"].ToString();
    AppCookies["EmpName"] = rd["EmpName"].ToString();
    AppCookies["EmpDepartment"] = rd["EmpDepartment"].ToString();

    AppCookies.Expires = dtExpiry;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(AppCookies);

    int Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return sEMPID.Value.ToString();
}
```

I am getting enumeration yielded no results.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Which line in the gives you the error @SPEEDOO ?

Comment: Do you get results if you run query in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: First of all, you should **check** that the `.Read()` call actually returns data: `if ( rd.Read()) { ..... }`. Secondly - **why** are you executing the query again with `int Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` ?? That makes absolutely no sense - you've already opened a reader and you're reading the data - `.ExecuteNonQuery` won't do you any good and won't help you get any results....

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya   //  SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader(); in this line i am not getting data above given

Comment: @jdweng  yeah i got the result in sql but not in controller

Comment: @marc_s can you simpliy this.but i am not getting any data in reader

Comment: the you are connecting to the Different Server or Database in the Server.  Make sure you are using the same Server/IP instance and the default database is correct.  In you connection string "DO NOT USE THE ATTACH MDF" file since the database is already attached to the server since it is working in SSMS.

Comment: @jdweng  but all other methods are working only this.In the sql datareader rd =cmd.executereader() this returns null values i.e enumeration yields no value

Comment: Then a parameter is different.  Make a temp version of procedure and then hard code the parameters.  Then one at a time pass each parameter and see which one is causing issue.

Comment: jdweng the output parameter only causing error                                     SqlParameter sEMPID = cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Int, 5);
sEMPID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;